# Algolia vue-instantsearch firing same query multiple times

Tags: vue.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

I'm trying to implement algolia with vue in a website and it's working fine for the most part, however every time I try to perform a search using a custom `input` field it fires **twice** per keystroke and it's causing our search operations to double for every use in the site.

As an example here's how the problematic code looks like:

HTML

```html
<div id="instant-search">
  <div class="main container instant-search">
    <ais-instant-search :query="query" :search-client="algoliaClient" index-name="instant_search">
      <ais-configure :query="query" :hits-per-page.camel="21" :min-word-sizefor-1-typo.camel="6"></ais-configure>
      <ais-search-box></ais-search-box>
      <input v-model="query" />
      <ais-hits></ais-hits>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```js
var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#instant-search',
      data: function() {
        return {
          algoliaClient: algoliasearch(
            'ALGOLIA_APP_ID',
            'ALGOLIA_API_KEY'
          ),
          query: '',
        };
      },
});
```

If you open the Network tab and try typing into the `<input v-model="query" />` field you'll see 2 requests going to Algolia however doing the same in the  `<ais-search-box>` field shows a single request for every keystroke which expected.

Is there a way to implement the same behaviour from `ais-search-box` into my input field? The reason I can't use this field in our website is because the search field in our website is outside the vue instance and I have to set the query with `vm.query = 'query'` when typing into this field. It's a legacy site which doesn't help and my choices are very limited.

Here's the same example in codepen using Algolia's test credentials: https://codepen.io/javier_ml/pen/RwNzWRZ

Comment: Does it also happen if you only have the custom input field without having the `<ais-search-box>` at the same time? Maybe having it both cause a re-update of the query property.

Comment: No if I remove the `<ais-search-box>` it still triggers multiple times.